# JQgrid: links column formatter doesn't work. Why?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I have a little problem, but I can't figured out how to fix it, So help me please!
In my JQgrid I want to add a column with just links, and this links just as image.
I have the formatter, but the column doesn't show anything. Can you tell me why this happen? What I've miss it?
Columns code:

```
colNames:['ID','Nombre','Cliente', 'Marca', 'Agregar soporte'], 
    colModel :[ 
      {name:'equi_id', index:'equi_id', width:25}, 
      {name:'equi_nombre', index:'equi_nombre', width:90}, 
      {name:'equi_cliente', index:'equi_cliente', width:90}, 
      {name:'equi_marca', index:'equi_marca', width:90},
      {name:'soporte', width:90, index:'equi_id', formatter: soporteFormatter}      
    ],
```

Formatter:

```
function soporteFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var cellValue = cellvalue;
      return "<a href='nuevo_soporte.php?equi_id="+cellValue+"><img src='../images/edit.gif' alt='" + cellvalue + "' title='" + cellvalue + "' /></a>";
  }
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your missing a single quote at the end of your href, and the equi_id should be acquired via the row object.

```
function soporteFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var cellValue = rowObject.equi_id;
    return "<a href='nuevo_soporte.php?equi_id=" + cellValue + "'><img src='../images/edit.gif' alt='" + cellValue + "' title='" + cellValue + "' /></a>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just tried, but the "soporte" column still doesn't load anything. I think that maybe the problem is in the colmodel, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: that's odd it worked in my sample after i added the single quote. Is the function being hit, and does cellvalue have a value that can be appended. Maybe add an alert(cellvalue) to your function or step through with firebug.

Comment: I tried, and the problem is that the colmodel can't call twice the same index. Do you know why??

Comment: not sure but if you need the value for equi_id in the column formatter you can use rowObject.equi_id instead of trying to assign it's index to that column